# Hyperlink in javascript, for mail subject

Tags: javascript, html

I have js code that opens a mailto dialog when pressing on link, it is working as "share with a friend" function:

```
setTimeout( function(){
            var subject, body, email_string;
            subject = oScript_x.post_title;

            body = "you got mail from";
            //body += "link: " + "<a href='" + location.href + "'>" + location.href + "  </a>";
            body += "link " + location.href;


            email_string = "mailto:?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + body;
            email_string = email_string.replace(/ /g, "%20" ).replace(/\n/g, "%0A");
```

I tried to use this :
    body += "link: " + "" + location.href + "  ";
But no luck...

So now I am only showing the link as text with no link.
I would appreciate help to have the link clickable and under an anchor text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not escaping things properly. Instead of manually replacing certain patterns, you should use `encodeURIComponent` for each of the parameters that you add.

In other words, your code should look like this:

```
var subject = ...  // whatever you do to create this string
var body = ... // whatever you do to create this string
var encodedSubject = encodeURIComponent(subject);
var encodedBody = encodeURIComponent(body);
var emailLink = 'mailto:?subject=' + encodedSubject + '&body=' + encodedBody;
// ... use emailLink
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael, 
My javascript is a bit limited, can you maybe guide me how exactly can i make this line work:
    body += "link: " + "<a href='" + location.href + "'>" + location.href + "  </a>";

I just want to show a link in my mail )

Comment: Sure. There are basically two ways you could do this. The first way involves using the Document Object Model (DOM) APIs such as document.createElement() and element.appendChild() to create these elements, in which case you can simply assign link.href = value to assign the "href" property of the link. Or you can do it as you are doing via string concatenation. When doing it that way, it is necessary to ensure that strings are properly escaped. What you are doing involves the entire URL and thus you would need to use encodeURI() to put it in your string. Personally, I recommend the other way.